# Cannot get custom fortune file to randomise entries

Tags: bsd, games

I have installed the traditional BSD fortune program on Debian using pkgsrc:
https://pkgsrc.se/games/fortune

The application comes with a set of builtin fortunes that work fine. The fortune files directory is at /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/.

I have added a fortune in French downloaded from:
http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/games/amusements/fortune/

So I downloaded fortune-fr.1585.tar.gz and downloaded to a temporary directory.

I have extracted the files and copied france and france.dat to /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/

```
$ sudo cp france* /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/
```

Files are there with the correct permissions:

```
$ ls -l /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/france*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 183371 Jun 28 14:50 /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/france
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6368 Jun 28 14:50 /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/france.dat
```

But calling the fortune only gives me the same result:

```
$ fortune france
Les pommes de terre cuites sont tellement plus faciles a dig�rer 
que les pommes en terre cuite ! Alphonse Allais
$ fortune france
Les pommes de terre cuites sont tellement plus faciles a dig�rer 
que les pommes en terre cuite ! Alphonse Allais
$ fortune france
Les pommes de terre cuites sont tellement plus faciles a dig�rer 
que les pommes en terre cuite ! Alphonse Allais
```

I can see the france file is full of entries:

```
$ wc  /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/france
  5672  31860 183371 /usr/pkg/share/games/fortune/france
```

So, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason not to install the `fortunes-fr` package?

Comment: Because it's not part of pkgsrc. And I'm not going into the pkgsrc vs Debian native packages debate because its off topic.

Comment: Right, I just wanted to make sure it wasn’t a case of “ah, I hadn’t realised it was already packaged in Debian”.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does `fortune` do more than `shuf -n 1`?